# Lualatex luaescapestring and variable expansion

Tags: luatex, expansion

I am trying to write the contents of `\foo` to a file using LuaLatex.
Consider the following example:

```latex
\newcommand{\abcd}{test}
\newcommand{\foo}{XXX \abcd}
\directlua{
   local f = {}
   f.foo = token.get_macro 'foo'
(...)
```

When writing the contents of `f.foo` to a file later, the content will contain the string `XXX \\abcd`.
If instead we change this to the following:

```
   f.foo = "\luaescapestring{\foo}"
```

The result will be the intended `XXX test`.

When the command `\foo` contains 'special' commands like `~`, the result will be `XXX \\protect \\unhbox \\voidb@x \\penalty \\@M \\ {} test`. Now this is ugly, but can be parsed/is workable. However, when commands like `\\` or `\xspace` are used, the compilation will fail, such as:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...

l.180 }
```

The error message seems to differ based on the command that was used.

Is there a way to expand the command `\foo` such that recursive expansion is performed and arbitrary special commands are protected/escaped or at the least compilation does not break?

**EDIT 1**

File `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
Test text
\newcommand{\abcd}{test}
\newcommand{\foo}{XXX \\ \abcd}
\directlua{
    local f = {}
    f.foo = "\luaescapestring{\foo}"
    local fd = io.open("test.out", "a")
    fd:write(f.foo)
    fd:flush()
    fd:close()
}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="lualatex" main.tex`

Above throws an error, but works with `\newcommand{\foo}{XXX \abcd}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: it would easier to answer if you provided a test file rather than unconnected fragments/ handling tex expansion from Lua is tricky it would be easiest if you use `\protected@edef` first to expand everything as much as is safe then wrote the resulting tokens to the file.

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion, I will look into `\protected@edef`. In the mean time I have added an example to the original post.

Comment: with `\newcommand{\foo}{XXX \abcd}` I get  [\di
rectlua]:1: bad argument #1 to 'close' (FILE* expected, got no value)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in field 'close'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.15 }

Comment: @Tom the error in the previous comment is as you have `.close` not `:close` as the last line of Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make "fragile commands safe in a moving argument" LaTex sets `\protect` to a suitable value, here the expansion happens while passing to Lua, but is otherwise similar to the expansion that happens in a TeX `\write`  `\string` is a suitable value here so

```
\documentclass[british]{report}


\begin{document}
Test text
\newcommand{\abcd}{test}
\newcommand{\foo}{XXX \\ \abcd}

{\let\protect\string
\directlua{
    local f = {}
    f.foo = "\luaescapestring{\foo}"
    local fd = io.open("test.out", "a")
    fd:write(f.foo)
    fd:flush()
    fd:close()
}}

\end{document}
```

which writes a file with content

```
XXX \\ test
```

Comment: You are a genius, this works! I just applied it to my original project and it expands most commands. Some commands like `\bullet` `\cmd` `\acs` are not expanded but escaped. I guess they can not be interpreted/stripped to a string and will have to be parsed manually.

Comment: @Tom we have some expl3 code to "purify" such strings to pure text (eg for use in pdf bookmarks) er but I'm not sure if it is released yet, let me check....

Comment: @Tom don't really have parse anything just make your macro that sets this up give expandable definitions so inside the group with `\let\protect\string` add `\def\bullet{•}`  then `\bullet` will expand to • during the write.